# Jquery Focus Issue

Tags: jquery, focus

I have the following code that would like to have a generic function for if possible. When needs to happen is the label on top needs to change color. I have a color gradient behind it so I need to use transparent PNG for the corners. The layout width needs to be liquid so I can't really change the HTML too much.`

```
<div class="inputBody">
<div class="inputtop"><span class="inputtoptext">Username</span></div>
<div><input type="text" size="25"></div>`
</div>

<script>
$('input').focus(function() {
    $(this).addClass("yellowinput");

});

$('input').blur(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("yellowinput");
});
</script>
```

`

Comment: Whats the issue ? does it not work ? what errors are you getting ?

Comment: Please **Imagine that you're someone else reading your question**, Do you have any idea what is that guy asking about?

Comment: I'm asking to change the background to text above the input. I have reformatted and made it easier to read. When you load the page "inputtoptext" had a blue background. I want to change it to yellow when you click on the text input box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make one piece of code that works on a unit like this.  All relevant id values are changed to class names and the whole piece is put into a container.  That lets us find the object associated with this input container in a generic way relative to the object that caused the event.

```
<div class="inputContainer">
    <span class="orderlabel-left">
        <img src="resources/images/labelbackground-left.png" class="leftsidecorneruser">
    </span>
    <span class="orderlabel orderlabelcommon">Username</span>
    <span class="orderlabel-right">
        <img src="resources/images/labelbackground-right.png" class="rightsidecorneruser">
    </span>
    <div>
        <input type="text" value="" name="" class="orderinput" size="40" tabindex="1" id="user">
    </div>
</div>


$('input').focus(function() {
    var container = $(this).closest(".inputContainer");
    container.find(".leftsidecorneruser").attr("src", "resources/images/yellowleft.png");
    container.find(".rightsidecorneruser").attr("src", "resources/images/yellowright.png");
    container.find(".orderlabelcommon").removeClass("orderlabel").addClass("yellowbackground");
}); 
$('input').blur(function() {
    var container = $(this).closest(".inputContainer");
    container.find(".leftsidecorneruser").attr("src", "resources/images/labelbackground-left.png");
    container.find(".rightsidecorneruser").attr("src", "resources/images/labelbackground-right.png");
    container.find(".orderlabelcommon").addClass("orderlabel").removeClass("yellowbackground");
});
```

FYI, a different approach could be done with a lot less code and using mostly CSS rules like this:

```
$('input').focus(function() {
    $(this).closest("inputContainer").addClass("hasFocus");
});

$('input').blur(function() {
    $(this).closest("inputContainer").removeClass("hasFocus");
});
```

Then, you would just make all your CSS rules contingent upon whether an object has a parent CSS class `.hasFocus` or not.  The images would have to change to be background images, but they can even be done in CSS too.

Comment: That worked. I had never used the the closest function before.

Comment: @DavidNuckols - as you're new here on stackoverflow, do you realize that the way you contribute back to the community when you ask a question is that you tell the community which answer answered your question best by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer?  That will also earn you some reputation points which will eventually allow you to have other privileges here.

Answer (score -1):

You should really wait for the DOM to be ready before setting up the event handlers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // your code here
    });
</script>
```

I don't know if this will solve your problem (as others pointed out, it's not clear from the question), but this is good practice. You should also put the `script`-tag between the `<head>`-tags.

Comment: It looks like his script is in the bottom of the `body` so it doesn't matter.

Comment: This is not required if the javascript code is physically located after the DOM elements in the file.

Comment: Just edited my comment to note that it's only common practice to do so.

Comment: For fastest displaying pages, it is actually recommended to put scripts at the end of the HTML body so the HTML can be parsed and displayed before scripts are parsed and run.  Scripts do not have to be in the head tag.  This is really not an answer to the OP's question in any way.